# Changing structure of files github

Tags: git, github

Right now in my github repo, I have the folders of several packages, but I want to put them into one folder called "src." How can I do this without deleting/remaking the repo or having to do massive merging?

Currently: folder1, folder2, folder3, folder4

I want: src > (folder1, folder2, folder3, folder4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move them, git will pick up on it:

```
$ mv folder1 src/; mv folder2 src/; mv folder3/ src/; mv folder4/ src/
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Moved folders 1-4 to src/"

[master c5d9ecf] Moved folders 1-4 to src/
 4 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename {folder1 => src/folder1}/file.txt (100%)
 rename {folder2 => src/folder2}/file.txt (100%)
 rename {folder3 => src/folder3}/file.txt (100%)
 rename {folder4 => src/folder4}/file.txt (100%)
```

Comment: This won't affect the guy that pulls?

Comment: Yes, it does when you push the commit that contains the folders moved into `src/`.